# Auto generation of insert query at runtime for Oracle / SQL Server from table name

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to generate insert queries from a given table name.

I have multiple tables for which I need to dynamically generate columns and then insert statements but I can't find the right resources.

One thing which I'm thinking is to get the table schema and do it from there.

If there is any existing library which anyone knows it'll be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Use any ORM framework rather than reinventing the wheel

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. The problem is that we have multiple tables and more tables will be added constantly. How can I use an ORM for such requirement?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, have a look at `USER_TABLES` and `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` (`USER_`, as owned by you; or `ALL_`, available to you; or `DBA_`, all tables in the database).

Comment: I do have the table information. Im looking for the resources in C#

Comment: Aha; I see. I thought you are looking for data dictionary views that contain information about tables and columns. Unfortunately, I don't speak C# so I can't assist, sorry.

Comment: no worries. thank you so much for your answer :) Good day